# NullPointerException when execute 'mvn liquibase:diff'

Tags: maven, liquibase, jhipster

Hy jHipsters,

I've a null pointer exception when I run the mvn command line liquibase:diff on a @manyToMany relationship defined below

class user.java

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "USER_PROJECT",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

int the class project.java

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:diff (default-cli) on project app: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:diff (default-cli) on project app: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:373)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:123)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:100)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.performLiquibaseTask(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:176)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:369)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:13)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:121)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
    at liquibase.diff.output.StandardObjectChangeFilter$Filter.matches(StandardObjectChangeFilter.java:104)
    at liquibase.diff.output.StandardObjectChangeFilter.include(StandardObjectChangeFilter.java:70)
    at liquibase.diff.output.StandardObjectChangeFilter.includeMissing(StandardObjectChangeFilter.java:51)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorChain.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorChain.java:28)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorFactory.fixMissing(ChangeGeneratorFactory.java:99)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.generateChangeSets(DiffToChangeLog.java:145)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:125)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:76)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:64)
    at liquibase.command.DiffToChangeLogCommand.run(DiffToChangeLogCommand.java:61)
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:8)
    ... 27 more
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING NOT A CLEAN SOLUTION, some side effects. I share it anyway in case it helps.

I succeed to make it work by downgrading the liquibase version from 3.3.2 to 3.3.1. Here's more details:

```
    <liquibase-hibernate4.version>3.5</liquibase-hibernate4.version>
    <liquibase-slf4j.version>1.2.1</liquibase-slf4j.version>
    <liquibase.version>3.3.1</liquibase.version>
```

The liquibase:diff run without error and create a change log with my model's changes **however it contains drop table directives of my Oauth2 database tables**.

It seems the diffExcludeObjects in the liquibase's plugin configuration is ignored or is not working with version 3.3.1.

Some related links of similar issues:

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/754

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/76

Comment: This work for me! As you say the diffExcludeObjects not working and this is normal it appears in the 3.3.2 release...
http://www.liquibase.org/2015/01/liquibase-3-3-2-released.html

waiting for correction from liquibase...

Comment: I open a new issue with jhipster asking for a better work arround: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1838. I trust hips to be better than me to open an issue with liquibase.

Comment: As requested by Jhipster's team (the big J himself) I opened an issue to Liquibase: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/88